# Streaming audio file in C on linux

Tags: c, linux, file, unix, audio

I have a .au audio file and am reading it in parts using fread. However when i write this to /dev/audio  there is no sound being played. Do I need to do something or is the system supposed to play back as soon as I write to /dev/audio. I am not getting any errors.

```
    player = open("/dev/audio", O_WRONLY, 0);
    if (player < 0) 
    {
     perror("Opening /dev/audio failed\n");
     exit(1);
    }
    while(1)
    {
        //code to read from the file writes to buf 1000 bytes per read
        //fread(buf,1000, 1, audioFile); //server side

        write(player, buf, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: The contents of the file which are read

Comment: Where are they read?

Comment: On the server side. added snippet in code

Comment: and `cp file.au /dev/audio` does what for you?  Is that audible?

Comment: Your `fread` call seem to be wrong. It should be `fread(buf,1, 1000, audioFile)`

Comment: No, that doesn't play any sound. However this does: 'pacat file.au > /dev/audio'

Comment: Well, I guess dumping a raw binary data without any timing information won't yield any good.

Comment: The syntax of fread is correct. I nead 1 block of size 1000

Comment: The timing information will be handled later but it should still play right? Thats just not happening

Comment: Second parameter of `fread` is the *size* of the elements. Third parameter is the *number* of elements.

Comment: @duckvader What will it play? You just dump all of the information in a single moment. It does not have any duration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127752/discussion-between-duckvader-and-eugene-sh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with Ubuntu. I tried the same on a Gentoo installation in my lab and the sound can be heard